# How to make an MQTT connection from a large number of objects? QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, mqtt

I have a "cell" class that describes some kind of smart device. I've got plenty of them. Each of these devices must implement a connection to the server. I have written methods in the "cell" class.

**cell.cpp**

```
#include "cell.h"

#include <QDateTime>
#include <QMessageBox>

cell::cell(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void cell::Connect(){
    m_client = new QMqttClient(this);
    m_client->setHostname("192.111.11.111");
    m_client->setPort(1883);

    m_client->connectToHost();

    QObject::connect(m_client, &QMqttClient::stateChanged, this, &cell::updateLogStateChange);
    QObject::connect(m_client, &QMqttClient::disconnected, this, &cell::brokerDisconnected);
}


void cell::MsgReceive(){
    connect(m_client, &QMqttClient::messageReceived, this, [this](const QByteArray &message, const QMqttTopicName &topic) {
         const QString content =
                    QLatin1String(" Received Topic: ")
                    + topic.name()
                    + QLatin1String(" Message: ")
                    + message
                    + QLatin1Char('\n');
         setMsg(content);
    });
}

void cell::Publish()
{
    QString topic = "topic/";
    QString msg = "HELLO";
    m_client->publish(topic, msg.toUtf8());
}

void cell::Subscribe()
{
    QString topic = "topic/";
    auto subscription = m_client->subscribe(topic);
    if (!subscription) {
        return;
    }
}
void cell::updateLogStateChange()
{
    const QString content = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString()
                    + QLatin1String(": State Change")
                    + QString::number(m_client->state())
                    + QLatin1Char('\n');
    setLogState(content);
}

void cell::brokerDisconnected()
{

}
```

In the main window, I create objects through a loop and call the connection methods as an example, just to get a message in the ListWidget.
But it doesn't show up, what's the problem? I would be very grateful if you help me. I just started learning c++.

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <modelcell.h>
#include <cell.h>
#include <QThread>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QVector <cell *> listcell;

    QString val;
    QFile file;
    file.setFileName("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\cell.json");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    val = file.readAll();
    file.close();

    QJsonParseError error;
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8(), &error);
    if (doc.isObject())
       {
         QJsonObject json = doc.object();
         QJsonArray jsonArray = json["cell"].toArray();
         foreach (const QJsonValue & value, jsonArray)
            {
                if (value.isObject())
                {
                    QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
                    QString id = obj["ID"].toString();
                    QString name = obj["Name"].toString();
                    QString IP = obj["IP"].toString();
                    QString status = obj["status"].toString();

                    cell * cell_obj = new cell;
                    cell_obj->setName(name);
                    cell_obj->setID(id);
                    cell_obj->setIP(IP);
                    cell_obj->setStatus(status);

                    cell_obj->Connect();
                    cell_obj->MsgReceive();
                    cell_obj->Subscribe();
                    cell_obj->Publish();

                    listcell.append(cell_obj);

                }
            }
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < listcell.size(); i++){
            ui->listWidget->addItem(listcell[i]->getName() + " | " + listcell[i]->getID() + " | " + listcell[i]->getIP()+ " | " + listcell[i]->getStatus());
            ui->listWidget->addItem(listcell[i]->getMsg());
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I want the listWidget to display a "hello" message from each created object. But it doesn't happen. Where is the mistake?

Comment: I can't comment on why your C++ doesn't work, but a single application shouldn't need to make a separate MQTT client connection for each device. If that is the case then your topic structure and ACL is very broken. All this should be possible with a single client.

Comment: @hardillb Got it, thanks. How can I connect multiple objects using single mqtt client?

Comment: A single client with the device ids encoded in the topiy